# cannot implicitly convert type void to object error in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using this in an application where I am allowed to extend its functionality using my own code.

It's been coded in C#.

`Result()` will return the answer it gets from my Node.js server (`FinalResponse`) and I'm going to access it in the application like below, but I get the error in the title when I try to use EchoOut().

```
var returnedValue = Lib.Result();
App.EchoOut(returnedValue); // EchoOut allows you to test the function you wrote, it echoes string on the screen, but in this case, it gives an error.
```

Error

```
cannot implicitly convert type void to object
```

When I test the `Lib.Result()` alone, I see the request is being made by the app, but I can't assign the returned value to a variable.

How can I assign the `FinalResponse's` value to `returnedValue` variable?

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace MainNameSpace
{
  public class Lib
  {
    public void Result()
    {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("192.168.1.101:8000/mytest");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string FinalResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(FinalResponse);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: void means 'this method has nothing to return' instead you have a method that need to return a string.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the return type of the `Result` method to `string` and return the `FinalResponse` instead of writing it to the console.

```
public string Result() // <-- "string" instead of "void"
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("192.168.1.101:8000/mytest");

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd(); // <-- return the result
    }
}
```

It is also considered good practice to wrap the code using disposable objects (in this case, objects of type `HttpWebResponse`, `Stream` and `StreamReader`) with `using` blocks.

I also took the liberty of using `var` instead of explicitly writing out the types of the variables because the types are already obvious from the right hand sides of the declarations.

Comment: It works amazing. Thank you, given that you're the first to answer, I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: I'm glad it works! I also modified the code to use `using` blocks to properly dispose the respose, the stream and the stream reader.

Answer (score 3):

Your method Result()  is of type void. But you are trying to assign a return value. Change the return type and use "return"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not *returning* anything from your function. Rewrite it to this and it will work:

```
public string Result()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("192.168.1.101:8000/mytest");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string FinalResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();
    //Console.WriteLine(FinalResponse);
    return FinalResponse;
}
```

Additionally, here's how to make the C# a little more idiomatic in terms of case conventions etc:

```
public string Result()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("192.168.1.101:8000/mytest");
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var finalResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();
    return finalResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and additional information, I'm trying to understand it. It works now, I'll have to accept Botond Balázs's answer (he was first) but I upvoted your answer.
Again, thank you for your time and patience!